# Do not override a value in SetParameters.xml with defaultValue when make web deployment IIS Windows Server

Tags: xml, iis, web-deployment

I use [custom parametrization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110).aspx) for web deployment in order to change something in Web.config when deploy.

I have a file called `parameters.xml` which contains:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="CustomParam" description="Custom param" defaultValue="/test">
    <parameterEntry kind="TextFile" scope="\\Web\.config$" match="PARAM_DIRECTORY" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

and result in `SetParameters.xml` is:

```
<setParameter name="CustomParam" value="/test" />
```

And in Web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" path="PARAM_DIRECTORY/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Well, if I change value in `SetParameters.xml` for `CustomParam` to `/foo` and I make a deployment then in Web.config file I still see `/test` instead of `/foo`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" path="/test/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>  <!-- I want to see /foo/Error -->
</httpErrors>
```

How to achieve that ?

I run cmd like:

```
MyPackage.cmd /Y -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `defaultValue` instead of `value` like this `<setParameter name="CustomParam" defaultValue="/test" />`?

Comment: Nope, otherwise you'll ger error: `CustomParam` cannot be null or empty

Comment: That was too easy :D Any reason why you don't use web.config transform? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Need for automation web deployment, which web transform doesn't help too much.